# Allowing just white space in 'Required' data annotation

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I am using the `[Required]` data annotation on a string. This works just as intended, however it deems an input *only* consisting of white space to be invalid.

Is there any way to change this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is an `AllowEmptyStrings` property on the `RequiredAttribute`.  See if that helps.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.requiredattribute.allowemptystrings

Answer (score 5):

According to [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.requiredattribute.allowemptystrings?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8#System_ComponentModel_DataAnnotations_RequiredAttribute_AllowEmptyStrings) you can use `AllowEmptyStrings`:

```
 [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false)]
 public string CompanyName { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 3):

Although `[Required(AllowEmptyStrings = true)]` does allow whitespace, it also allows actual empty strings.

With `[StringthLength(...)]`, you can permit whitespace but still forbid empty strings:

```
[StringLength(int.MaxValue, MinimumLength = 1)]
public string CompanyName { get; set; }
```